# Ignore a centain gesture on UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to customise `UIImagePickerController`. I want, when the camera of `UIImagePickerController` starts, it ignores all the pinch gesture only.

Here is what I tried, but it does not work: I added a overlay, with a pinch gesture recognised associated with it. The problem is, the overlay also disabled all the other gestures:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController  <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *picker;
@end
```

here is part of the controller implementation:

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.delegate = self;
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = YES;

CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
screenBounds.size.height -= 100;
UIView *cameraOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRec = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doPinch)];
[cameraOverlay addGestureRecognizer:pinchRec];
[self.picker.view addSubview:cameraOverlay];
```

`doPinch` is a method that does nothing

Answer (score 0):

`self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;`

and custom you Camera Controls in `cameraOverlay`

Comment: Do you mean I need to implement the camera control in `cameraOverlay` myself?